# EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=EXC_ARM_DA_ALIGN

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, exc-bad-access

I've tested my code with 3 x iPhone 5's, a 5s, 6, 6s, and 7.

I'm getting the above error on all of the iPhone 5 devices only. No idea what is going on here but perhaps the fact that the 5's are 32bit devices may be a clue?

I'm calling the following method from a viewcontroller class

```
func startRecording() {
    disableControls()

    CoreDataStack.shared.performForegroundTask { (context) in
            let sessionInfo = SessionInfo(context: context)
            sessionInfo.startTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
            sessionInfo.userId = self.config.userId
            sessionInfo.devicePosition = self.config.devicePosition.rawValue
            sessionInfo.deviceType = self.config.deviceType.rawValue
            sessionInfo.deviceNumber = self.config.deviceNumber
            sessionInfo.deviceSide = self.config.deviceSide.rawValue

            do {
                    try context.obtainPermanentIDs(for: [sessionInfo])
            } catch {
                    print("Error obtaining permanent ID for session info record")
                    return
            }

            CoreDataStack.shared.saveViewContextAndWait()

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    guard sessionInfo.objectID.isTemporaryID == false else {
                            print("ObjectID is temporary")
                            return
                    }

                    self.recording = true
                    self.statusLabel.text = "Recording..."
                    self.recordManager.start(sessionUID: sessionInfo.uid)
            }
    }
}
```

The config variable is a simple struct:

```
struct Configuration {
    var userId: String = "Unknown"
    var deviceType: DeviceType = .phone // enum: String
    var deviceSide: DeviceSide = .notApplicable // enum: String
    var deviceNumber: Int16 = 1 
    var devicePosition: DevicePosition = .waist  // enum: String
}
```

The CoreDataStack is here:

```
final class CoreDataStack {
    static let shared = CoreDataStack()
    private init() {}

    var errorHandler: (Error) -> Void = { error in
            log.error("\(error), \(error._userInfo)")
    }

    private struct constants {
            static let persistentStoreName = "Model"
    }

    private lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
            let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: constants.persistentStoreName)
            container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { [weak self] (storeDescription, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                            self?.errorHandler(error)
                    }
            })
            return container
    }()

    lazy var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
            self.persistentContainer.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump
            self.persistentContainer.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
            try! self.persistentContainer.viewContext.setQueryGenerationFrom(.current)
            return self.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }()

    private lazy var backgroundContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
            let context = self.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
            context.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyStoreTrump
            return context
    }()

    func performForegroundTask(_ block: @escaping (NSManagedObjectContext) -> Void) {
            self.viewContext.performAndWait {
                    block(self.viewContext)
            }
    }

    func performBackgroundTask(_ block: @escaping (NSManagedObjectContext) -> Void) {
            backgroundContext.perform {
                    block(self.backgroundContext)
            }
    }

    func saveBackgroundContext() {
            viewContext.performAndWait {
                    do {
                            if self.viewContext.hasChanges {
                                    try self.viewContext.save()
                            }
                    } catch {
                            self.errorHandler(error)
                    }

                    self.backgroundContext.perform {
                            do {
                                    if self.backgroundContext.hasChanges {
                                            try self.backgroundContext.save()
                                            self.backgroundContext.refreshAllObjects()
                                    }
                            } catch {
                                    self.errorHandler(error)
                            }
                    }
            }
    }

    func saveViewContext() {
            viewContext.perform {
                    if self.viewContext.hasChanges {
                            do {
                                    try self.viewContext.save()
                            } catch {
                                    self.errorHandler(error)
                            }
                    }
            }
    }

    func saveViewContextAndWait() {
            viewContext.performAndWait {
                    if self.viewContext.hasChanges {
                            do {
                                    try self.viewContext.save()
                            } catch {
                                    self.errorHandler(error)
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

The code is bombing out on the following line in the `startRecording` method:

```
try context.obtainPermanentIDs(for: [sessionInfo])
```

**Edit:**

I've created a stripped down test application consisting of only the `CoreDataStack` and a model with one entity with one attribute of type string. I'm still getting the same error on 3x iPhone 5's only. 5s, 6, 6s, 7 all work fine.

It would imply the problem lies with the `CoreDataStack` perhaps?

Github repo [here](https://github.com/doovers/CoreDataStack/tree/master)

Comment: The github project is missing the CoreDataStack.swift file. Copying from here results 'log' not available. After commenting 'log' out and running I get 'success' on all simulators, including iPhone 5. Do you get an error on the simulator or on an actual device only?

Comment: Did you find a solution or a workaround for this problem ? I have more or less the same issue and cannot figure it out.

Comment: @AlexandreG. A little late to the party but see my answer if you haven't found a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of people have asked if I solved this, so here is what I did. This is not really a solution but more of a workaround. It may not be appropriate for everyone but worked for me.

All I did was remove the line

```
try! self.persistentContainer.viewContext.setQueryGenerationFrom(.current)
```

from the `CoreDataStack` and the issue went away...

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a couple of guesses based on a short look at your code.

The old-school developer in me is drawn to the Configuration member `var deviceNumber: Int16 = 1`. Incorrect alignment settings or old compilers might cause the next item to have the wrong alignment. You could try making it the last item in the struct.

Another item which stands out is the assignment `sessionInfo.deviceNumber = self.config.deviceNumber`.  This looks to be assigning an Int16 to an NSNumber which may be a problem. (I am assuming that SessionInfo is an NSManagedObject based on the overall code and its initializer taking a context argument. That would mean all numeric members are NSNumbers.)

Try changing the line to

```
sessionInfo.deviceNumber = NSNumber(int:self.config.deviceNumber)
```

I'm not yet familiar with the iOS 10 additions to Core Data, but from what I'm reading the viewContext is read-only.  But viewContext is being used to create a new object in this code.  Is the Xcode console showing any more information when you get to this point in the debugger?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried that and stripped out everything I could think of to resolve the problem but nothing worked. I created a new project with the minimum code required to duplicate the problem. See edited question for repo link. Would appreciate if you could have a look!

Comment: Did you try both parts?  What about the NSNumber part?  (I edited my answer to include a sample line.)

Comment: Yes I tried with NSNumber too. But in the sample project I removed all numbers and only have a single string attribute in the entity and it's still happening.

Comment: Added another idea at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: No further info in the console unfortunately. I might try and create the object on the background context and see if that works... Will report back when I've tested that!

Comment: Ok, so interestingly, creating the object on a background context worked. However, in the main app, I'm having a similar error with an `NSFetchedResultsController` at `performFetch()`. Again I'm using the viewContext but I'm not writing anything with it. I'm going to update the test app to include that and try it out to see if the issue persists

Comment: @doovers - did you find a solution to this? I'm also experiencing a crash on iPhone 5 during a fetch, and I can't figure it out!

Comment: I did discover this too a while after I left the comment! ;) Was going to answer, but you beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

`NSPersistentContainer` is a setup for a core data stack with clear expectation on how to use it. You are misusing it. `viewContext` is readonly so remove `performForegroundTask`, `saveViewContext` and `saveViewContextAndWait`. Don't change the `viewContext`'s mergePolicy. In `performBackgroundTask` just use `NSPersistentContainer`'s performBackgroundTask which has the same method signature.  Don't use `newBackgroundContext`.  If you are using `NSPersistentContainer` your CoreDataStack should be doing next to nothing.

If you want a different custom stack unlike what `NSPersistentContainer` sets up then don't use `NSPersistentContainer` - just create your own stack.  But the setup that you are trying to write has major problems.  Writing from both background contexts and the viewContext has **major** problems when writes happen at the same time.  mergePolicy can help that but you can end up missing information that you thought you saved.  You are much better off learning to use the stack that `NSPersistentContainer` sets up.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. What you're saying makes sense but one thing I'm not clear on is why I can't use `newBackgroundContext`. The reason I'm doing that is that I want a common context to create multiple objects on and save in batches to limit I/O. Is that contra indicated? Also, can you point me any good references for appropriate use of `NSPersistentContainer` too if you have any good resources.

Comment: Saving in batches is a good idea.  I would suggest using `performBackgroundTask` to do that.  It has a lot of advantages over `newBackgroundContext`.  First it ensures that your code is executed on the correct thread.  Second it ensure that you don't have two writes happening at the same time.  Third it makes a clear expectation that these context are disposable - you use them in your block and then don't use them again.  I have found that is a better system over having background context staying around.

Comment: I'm a little confused here. If I create entities using multiple calls to `performBackgroundTask` how can I save in batches? I can't create all entities in one block hence my reasoning for the use of `newBackgroundContext` to create a common context for each new entity. What am I missing here?

Comment: Lets say you have 100 entity and want to save them in batches of 25.  You call `performBackgroundTask ` 4 times, and each time you get a new context.  You use the context to insert the 25 items, then save the context and then discard the context an all pointers to it.  If you have some common entity that you need them all to link to (for example it is 100 articles that all have the same author) then you have to refetch that entity for every context.